# Service-to-Service Communication in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, nginx-ingress, amazon-eks, amazon-elb

I have deployed my Kubernetes cluster on EKS. I have an ingress-nginx which is exposed via load balancer to route traffic to different services. In ingress-nginx first request goes to auth service for authentication and if it is a valid request then I allow it move forward.
Let say the request is in Service 1 and now from there, it wants to communicate to Service 2. So if I somehow want my request to go directly to ingress not via load balancer and then from ingress to service 2.

1. Is is possible to do so?
2. Will it help in improving performance as I bypassed load balancer?
3. As the request is not moving through load balancer so load balancing won't take place, is it a serious concern?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was fairly new when I asked this.

But the answer to this is that you can expose your private ingress controller using both Cluster IP and Load Balancer.

So, any communication from outside of your Kubernetes cluster can come via the load balancer, and internal communication can be done via Cluster IP. However, to access the private ingress load balancer, you need to allow traffic to it by whitelisting IPs.

It's worth noting that Cluster IP does have load balancing capabilities. While it might not be as robust as a dedicated load balancer, I found that it provided better performance for my use case.

Answer (score 1):

1/ Is it possible: short answer, no.

There are edge cases, that would require for someone to create another Ingress object exposing Service2 in the first place. Then, you could trick the Ingress into routing you to some service that might not otherwise be reachable (if the DNS doesn't exist, some VIP was not yet exposed, ...)

There's no real issue with external clients bypassing the ELB, as long as they can not join all ports on your nodes, just the ones bound by your ingress controller.

2/ Bypassing the loadbalancer: won't change much in terms of performance.

If we're talking about a TCP loadbalancer, getting it away would help track real client IPs, though. Figuring out how to change it for an HTTP loadbalancer may be better -- though not always easy.

3/ Removing the LoadBalancer: if you have several nodes hosting replicas of your incress controller, then you would still be able to do some kind of DNS-based loadbalancing. Though for sure, it's not the same as having a real LB.

In AWS, you could find a middle ground setting up health-check based Route53 Records: set one for each node hosting an ingress controller, create another regrouping all healthy ingress nodes, then change your existing ingress FQDN records so they'ld all point to your new route53 name. You'ld be able to do TCP/HTTP checks against EC2 instances IPs, that's usually good enough. But again: DNS loadbalancing can suffer from outdated browser caches, some ISP not refreshing zones, ... LB is the real thing.